# Az CLI first request takes longer time in a stateless machine

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault, azure-cli

I have a stateless machine that has Az CLI installed in the image (Windows 2022 server) in the following way

```
Write-Host "Installing Azure CLI"
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://aka.ms/installazurecliwindows -OutFile .\AzureCLI.msi; 
cmd /c dir AzureCLI.msi
$p = Start-Process -Filepath msiexec.exe -Wait -ArgumentList '/I AzureCLI.msi ALLUSERS=1 /quiet' -PassThru
write-host "Exit code: $($p.exitcode)"
Remove-Item .\AzureCLI.msi
```

In a request to this machine on run time (i.e. A fresh VM with the image on it accepts the request.) the az cli command to fetch secrets from KeyVault is taking almost 50s whereas if I perform an Az CLI command before fetching secrets and perform fetching secrets then it takes couple of seconds. But the first one does take 50s. I am fetching secret in the following way

```
az keyvault secret show --name $secretName --vault-name $vaultName --query "value"
```

So I am thinking the first AzCLI call is taking a very long time.

Is there something I can do reduce time taken during run time?

Comment: Issue might be related to the installation of MSI package CLI every time. Instead of downloading it again and again, install it once using [installer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/install-azure-cli-windows?tabs=azure-cli). Did you try this way. @eoeo

Comment: Installation of the MSI is in the image it is not happening during runtime. MSI is downloaded and installed before the VM is given to run. @Jahnavi

Answer (score 0):

Just because it's a stateless. It hibernates when inactive for a while, then takes a few times to run again. There are some ways to improve the performance:

- Config the taken time to hibernate for the machine.
- Config timeout for the request and re-attempt it once or twice on the timed out request.
- Leave the machine always on.
- You can pay for a better machine with a higher power so that it can go back to running state faster.
- Or it's maybe an illegal way that I used to trigger the machine, that is calling a no-return request (pre-flight) or auth request before sending the main request. So make sure the main can be triggered successfully, and the user is authed

Comment: The machine is always on